# Can I override Magento Varien classes?

Tags: magento

I know how to override Mage classes (any class within `app/code/core`)
My question is how to override Varien classes? (classes within `lib/Varien`)

If I want to override `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu`
I create a class `MyCompany_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu` under `app/code/local/MyCompany/Adminhtml/Block/Page/Menu.php`

I name it like:

```
 class MyCompany_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu
```

Now Magento uses my class `MyCompany_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu` instead of `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu`

My question is: where should I put the new class, and how to name it, to override, for example  `Varien_Date` (`lib/Varien/Date.php`)

Thanks

Comment: sorry to disagree, but copy to local is not an acceptable way of overriding Magento's core

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**If you must**, copy the file and path to the *local* codepool and make the necessary changes. There is no configuration mapping to change the class name.

Explanation: see the bootstrapping in *app/Mage.php*. There is a load order set for the codepools and libraries in the following order:

1. *app/code/local/*
2. *app/code/community/*
3. *app/code/core/*
4. *lib/*

Typically, `Varien_Autoload` is responsible for mapping classnames such as `Varien_Data_Collection_Db`, `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`, or `Zend_Db_Select` to relative filenames (*Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php*, *Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php*, and *Zend/Db/Select.php* respectively). These file locations are then passed to `include()`, which internally uses the load order set in the bootstrap. Therefore, if the file *Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php* is present under one of the "earlier" locations, *that* version of the class definition will be used.

These type of modifications may be justified, but they should be well-considered and documented, as the entire definition will be owned by you and any upgrades will need to be merged in the future. It would be good to know what you would like to change, as someone else may have a slightly less invasive option.

Comment: Thanks, my changes must be within my module folder because I am creating a redistribuable module.

Comment: @skafandri if you need to change the core you are probably doing it wrong

Comment: Exactly! I definitely don't want to change the core, I just want to redefine some classes, I precisely want to redefine some toHtml() methods.

Comment: I'd really like for you to update your question with the changes that you'd like to make to form rendering...

Comment: Make sure you restart PHP-FPM.

Comment: @AntonS even the part of the lib/core that sets the executable bit on all uploaded files?  People can claim all day long that its the web-server's job to prevent said execution, but it's still just plain wrong for untrusted content to have the ugo+rwx mask.  It's my belief that Varien did it wrong. :-\  *I should further specify that by "changing the core" I mean implementing the proper overrides in the community and local code pools depending on the context.

Comment: @LukeA.Leber do as you please man :) it's a 3 year old thread and Magento has seen lot of releases and sec issues between this time. They have got lot of things right and wrong